# Android ImageView: How to prevent scaling with ScaleType.CENTER?

Tags: android, imageview, scaling

According to the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html), using the CENTER attribute will not perform any scaling on the image. Yet, when loading a PNG via XML like shown below, it appears significantly larger than it should be.

What's going on?

I figure the image is being scaled when it's loaded, but why? Is there some manifest tag missing, or should I be using a different folder?

```
<ImageView
    android:src="@drawable/auth_logo"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:scaleType="center"></ImageView>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Found the solution. The image needs to be in the `drawable-hdpi` folder apparently. Not sure why a density independent image should be in a folder with a density label, but oh well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scaling of image is caused by difference between your image's DPI and screen DPI.
Android manages scaling so that DPI matches.

Image's DPI is determined by res source folder where image is stored (drawable / drawable-hdpi / etc), and actual screen density, which is given physically and is fixed for given device.

To avoid scaling, put your image into res/drawable-nodpi folder.

Comment: Thanks. I went as far as to check there was no density attribute in the PNG header!